# Strongly typed Immutable.js Records in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, immutable.js

I'm unable to find a good resource for this question. Essentially I want to describe types for my data using an interface in TypeScript, but my data is Immutable.js records which appears to complicate matters, please see my example below.

```
interface tree extends Immutable.Map<string, any> {
  readonly id: number,
  readonly type: number
}

let trees = Immutable.List<tree[]>([
  Map<tree>({
     id: 101,
     type: 1
  }),
  Map<tree>({
     id: 201,
     type: 3
  })
])
```

Questions with the above:

1. Why do I have to repeat the type of each map in my list? Shouldn't the type be simply be declared by the `<tree[]>` when creating the list? And then any Map added to the list be type checked against this?
2. At present this example errors, stating that "property 'id' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'tree'. Which makes sense! However, reading the documentation, I can't work out how to get it to work? Reading the docs it states I need an ID but I want an array of maps, my signature in this case is just standard array ID's if I not much mistaken?

I've been working on this for days and I simply can't get it to work, it should be this simple according to everything I've read.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Immutable.js, but I tried this out and it compiled fine for me doing `Immutable.Map({id: 101, type: 1})` inside the list.  Calling `Map<tree>` doesn't make sense according to any of their typings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a `List` of `arrays` of `trees`, which is an extended `Map`. This is what it should look like:

```
let trees = Immutable.List<tree[]>(
    [ // List
        [ // Array
            <tree>Immutable.Map<any>({
                id: 101,
                type: 1
            }),
            <tree>Immutable.Map<any>({
                id: 201,
                type: 3
            })
        ]
    ]
);
```

Answering your questions:

1. You are not repeating the type of each map. Actually, you are calling a method `Map` that builds a map from an object. I added the `<tree>` cast because it is an array of `trees`, not maps.
2. You are trying something like:

   ```
   var singleTree: tree = Immutable.Map<tree>(
       { id: 101, type: 1 }
   );
   ```

   But your tree is a map of the `any` type. So, this is the right syntax:

   ```
   let singleTree: tree = <tree>Immutable.Map<any>(
       { id: 101, type: 1 }
   );
   ```

For the code above, we can simplify and force a type check if we create a `tree` function to wrap the `Map` function, so, the final solution would be:

```
function tree(obj: { [key: string]: any, id: number, type: number }): tree {
    return <tree>Immutable.Map<any>(obj);
}

let trees = Immutable.List<tree[]>(
    [ // List
        [ // Array
            tree({
                id: 101,
                type: 1
            }),
            tree({
                id: 201,
                type: 3
            })
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: This is what I'm after. Essentially you have validated that you can't use type checking for creating maps, I need to write my own (in a function or similar).